# A random string of numbers is invoking Dialogflow Actions

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have several actions published on Dialogflow that are getting invoked by random string of numbers such as the one below:
1,548,760,289,473 (1)

It invokes the assistant and then doesn't move pas the welcome message.   The training data is coming completely empty.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it might be the [Action health check](https://developers.google.com/actions/console/actions-health-check) that Google's bots perform throughout the day to ensure your Action responds.

If you examine the arguments, there will be one with the name `is_health_check`. The numbers don't appear to be random but look like they might be the number of milliseconds since midnight UTC, Jan 1, 1970 (the UNIX epoch start time).